# Error: "{\"message\":\"opening editor: exec: \\\"cmd.exe\\\": executable file not found in %PATH% - \"}

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

[image]

Docker Desktop unable to open in VS Code Rocket.chat this error happening when I click Open in VS Code.
Please give me solution, is anything to change in path variable or to make changes in docker desktop.
This error happen every time.